# magento code for getIsHomePage - with a twist

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Not sure how to explain this but i'm trying to run (2) php if statements together using a getIsHomePage block of code.   I need for the div replacement to be true if home page = yes and if "certain page url" = yes.  If not either of these two pages then the 'else' statement should be true.

Here is the code block I have now:

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
echo '<div class="main">';
} else {
echo '<div class="main container">';
}
?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below-mentioned code to check if you are on Home page or viewing your custom URL.

```
<?php
    $myCustomUrl = "...";

    if($this->getIsHomePage() || $myCustomUrl ) {
       echo 'Either you are on Homepage or your page URL is : ' .$myCustomUrl;
    } else {
       echo 'Nither you are on Homepage nor your page URL is : ' .$myCustomUrl;
    }
?>
```